# Invalid Data for Worksheet.name. must be [String]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am using `act_as_xlsx` for generating excel sheets. Everything is fine, except when I try to change the column headers with `en.yml`, I get this error

> Worksheet.name. must be [String]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can we take a look at the excel sheet?

Comment: excel sheet is not generating. the execution throws this error.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to insert "Worksheet.name" in your headers but ruby wants a String. Can you please provide more information on how the excel sheet is created?

Comment: I am using rails and exactly following this tutorial - http://axlsx.blog.randym.net/2011/12/axlsx-making-excel-reports-with-ruby-on.html. Using I18n section throws the above mentioned error.